# Datatable sorting clone

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I have two datatable's (one is hidden and one is visible) with same columns.

now if I apply sorting to the visible one that should be applied to the hidden one.

can anybody please help me how to do that with jquery/JS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd listen for events in the visible table, such as [order](https://datatables.net/reference/event/order), then in the event handler, apply the same search to the hidden table. The example on the link is showing how to get the ordering, so it should be fairly straightforward! :)